# Shuffling the list inside JSON Array

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

Can someone please suggest a way to shuffle the list inside the JSON array?

Let's say I have JSON array as shown below:

```
data:[{
"name" : "John",
"age":30,
"cars":["Ford", "BMW", "Fiat"]},
{
"name" : "Adam",
"age":31,
"cars":["Toyota", "Fiat", "Honda"]
},
{
"name" : "Tony",
"age":25,
"cars":["VW", "Mercedes", "Toyota"]
}]
```

How can I shuffle the list inside the JSON array of data so I can get the new data to be like:

```
shuffledData:[
{
"name" : "Adam",
"age":31,
"cars":["Toyota", "Fiat", "Honda"]
},
{
"name" : "Tony",
"age":25,
"cars":["VW", "Mercedes", "Toyota"]
},
{
"name" : "John",
"age":30,
"cars":["Ford", "BMW", "Fiat"]
}
]
```

Do I need to convert the JSON arraylist to regular arraylist first, then do collections.shuffle, then convert it back to the JSON arraylist again? This seems really complicated.

I would appreciate your help.

Thank you!

Comment: Well, if you want to do this in Java you'd need to convert the arrays to lists first and then shuffle. You might be able to write something which directly operates on the JSON but that would be even more complex. However, if you have access to JavaScript, e.g. by using Kotlin, you might be able to use that to directly work on the JSON arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static JSONArray shuffleJsonArray (JSONArray array) throws JSONException {
    // Implementing Fisher–Yates shuffle
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = array.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
          int j = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
          // Simple swap
          Object object = array.get(j);
          array.put(j, array.get(i));
          array.put(i, object);
        }
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you propose is not complicated. I'll leave it here in case you want to try it:

First you have to create a class for the objects of the JSONArray. Let´s call it PersonCars

```
public class PersonCars {
     public String name;
     public Integer age;
     public ArrayList<String> car;
     //All getters, setters and constructors
}
```

Then, take your JSONArray and parse it into an List with jackson library:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
...
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<PersonCars> myObjects = mapper.readValue(jsonArray, new TypeReference<List<PersonCars>>(){});
```

Use Collections.shuffle(myObjects) for randomize and finish convert the list to an JSONArray:

```
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(list);
```

It´s a bit long i know, but if you want to change something else in the array u will have it in java objects.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! I will try this. Do I need to parse all of the value in the JSONArray to the new List? Let's say I only care about the String name and Int age. Will this still work when I map the value back to the json? I am OK that the new json will only have the name and the age, as long as they are in shuffled order now.
And just to be clear, I can still call the string name by using json.getString("name") after it has already been shuffled?

Comment: If u say that u parse the json to a class with only name and age field i think this will work too. The second question, u have to take the string json (that you obtain with writeValueAsString) and parse it to a JSONObject (for example, JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(json)) and this JSONObject will have the same structure than your original json, so you can take the array "data" arraydata = jsonobject.getJSONArray("data") and navigate the JSONArray. If you need more code tell me what do you need and i will add another answer with code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and answer. I will try this first.